# XML Tags and Python

Tags: python, xml, file

Lets say I have a file called test.txt for example and side the file there is:

```
<name> sky </name>
```

How would I go about accessing this data from a file so that I can write it to a new file without using elementTree

Comment: Why on earth do you not want to use `ElementTree`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup`

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<name> sky </name>', 'lxml')
print soup.text
```

Comment: anyway to do it without importing anything?

Comment: Not even built-in modules such as `re`? You are gonna need a parser to do the job, either write it yourself(`re` would be a good choice) or use already existent ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @AER: Thanks mate! Never really thought about it before. So let's just leave regex to what it supposes to do

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '<name> sky </name>'
text.strip('</>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

out:

```
' sky '
```

this can handle some simple situation